# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I´m learning jsp, servlets and so. I got a Exception that I just cant find out the error. I kinda know the El cant find the field of the error but my JavaBean seens fine.The list that is passed to the jsp page also seens ok. 
Already changed the jsp and servlet alot and the exception keeps going.

Hope some1 can give me a hand.

Heres the Code and StackTrace:

StackTrace:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'nome' not found on type      java.lang.String
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:355)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:943)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.buscar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(buscar_jsp.java:253)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.buscar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(buscar_jsp.java:215)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.buscar_jsp._jspService(buscar_jsp.java:162)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:317)
    at control.ControleProduto.buscar(ControleProduto.java:140)
    at control.ControleProduto.execute(ControleProduto.java:65)
    at control.ControleProduto.doPost(ControleProduto.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Excessa no buscar An exception occurred processing JSP page /admin/buscar.jsp at line 33

30:             </tr>
31:             <c:forEach items="lista" var="prod">
32:                     <tr>
33:                         <td>${prod.nome }</td> 
34:                         <td>${prod.estoque }</td>
35:                         <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${prod.preco}" type="currency"/> </td>
36:                         <td> <fmt:formatDate value="${prod.validade}"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /> </td>


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /admin/buscar.jsp at line 33

30:             </tr>
31:             <c:forEach items="lista" var="prod">
32:                     <tr>
33:                         <td>${prod.nome }</td> 
34:                         <td>${prod.estoque }</td>
35:                         <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${prod.preco}" type="currency"/> </td>
36:                         <td> <fmt:formatDate value="${prod.validade}"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /> </td>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:317)
    at control.ControleProduto.buscar(ControleProduto.java:140)
    at control.ControleProduto.execute(ControleProduto.java:65)
    at control.ControleProduto.doPost(ControleProduto.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'nome' not found on type java.lang.String
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:355)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:943)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.buscar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(buscar_jsp.java:253)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.buscar_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(buscar_jsp.java:215)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.buscar_jsp._jspService(buscar_jsp.java:162)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    ... 38 more
```

Heres the bean:

```
package entity;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Produto {

    private Integer idProduto;
    private String nome;
    private Integer estoque;
    private Double preco;
    private Date validade;

    /*
     * Produto tem uma Categoria
     */
    private Categoria categoria;

    public Produto(Integer idProduto, String nome, Integer estoque,
            Double preco, Date validade) {
        super();
        this.idProduto = idProduto;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.estoque = estoque;
        this.preco = preco;
        this.validade = validade;
    }

    public Produto() {
        super();
    }

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }
    public Integer getIdProduto() {
        return idProduto;
    }
    public void setIdProduto(Integer idProduto) {
        this.idProduto = idProduto;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public Integer getEstoque() {
        return estoque;
    }
    public void setEstoque(Integer estoque) {
        this.estoque = estoque;
    }
    public Double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }
    public void setPreco(Double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }
    public Date getValidade() {
        return validade;
    }
    public void setValidade(Date validade) {
        this.validade = validade;
    }

    public static Date converterData(String data){
        String[] novaData = data.split("/");
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(
                new Integer(novaData[2]),
                new Integer(novaData[1]) - 1,
                new Integer(novaData[0]));
        return cal.getTime();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Produto [idProduto=" + idProduto + ", nome=" + nome
                + ", estoque=" + estoque + ", preco=" + preco + ", validade="
                + validade + "]";
    }


}
```

JSP pages:

Topo.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sistema de Controle de Produtos</title>
<!--  CSS Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
     href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--  Tabela com cores diferentes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
     href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/tabelacomcores.css">


</head>
<body>

    <!-- Como criar submenus? -->
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li><a href="index.jsp">Cadastrar</a></li>
                <li><a href="buscar.jsp">Consultar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sair</a>            

            </ul>
        </div> <!--  Menu -->
```

rodape.jsp

```
    </div> 

</div> <!--  container -->  

</body>
</html>
```

buscar.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="topo.jsp"></jsp:include>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<!-- Format library -->
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>


<h3 class="page-header">Buscar produtos</h3>

<form method="post" action="buscar.html">
    <div class="form-group">
        Nome :
        <input type="text" name="nome" value="${nome}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>

    ${msg }

    <c:if test="${fn:length(lista)>0}">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Estoque</th>
                <th>Preco</th>
                <th>Validade</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="lista" var="prod">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${prod.nome }</td> 
                        <td>${prod.estoque }</td>
                        <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${prod.preco}" type="currency"/> </td>
                        <td> <fmt:formatDate value="${prod.validade}"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /> </td>
                        <td>${prod.categoria.nomeCategoria }</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="editar.html?id=${prod.idProduto}" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
                            <a href="excluir.html?id=${prod.idProduto}" class="btn btn-danger"
                                onclick="return confirm('Deseja excluir realmente o produto?')">Excluir</a>
                        </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if> 

    <jsp:include page="rodape.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Dao.java

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Dao {

    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aula";
    private final String USER = "root";
    private final String PASS = "something";

    protected void open()throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    }

    protected void close()throws Exception{
        if(rs != null)
            rs.close();

        if(stmt != null)
            stmt.close();

        if(con != null)
            con.close();
    }

}
```

ProdutoDao.java

```
package persistence;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import entity.Categoria;
import entity.Produto;

public class ProdutoDao extends Dao {

    public void cadastrar(Produto prod)throws Exception{
        open();

        stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into produto (nome,estoque,preco,validade,idCategoria)"
                + " values(?,?,?,?,?)");

        stmt.setString(1, prod.getNome());
        stmt.setInt(2, prod.getEstoque());
        stmt.setDouble(3, prod.getPreco());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        stmt.setString(4, sdf.format(prod.getValidade()));
        stmt.setInt(5, prod.getCategoria().getIdCategoria());

        stmt.execute();

        close();
    }

    public List<Produto> buscar(String nome)throws Exception{
        open();

        stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from produto inner join categoria "
                + " on produto.idcategoria = categoria.idcategoria where nome like ?");
        stmt.setString(1, nome + "%");

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        List<Produto> lista = new ArrayList<Produto>();

        while(rs.next()){
            Produto prod = new Produto(rs.getInt("idproduto"), rs.getString("nome"), 
                    rs.getInt("estoque"), rs.getDouble("preco"), rs.getDate("validade"));
            Categoria cat = new Categoria(rs.getInt("idcategoria"), 
                    rs.getString("nomecategoria"));
            prod.setCategoria(cat);
            lista.add(prod);
        }
        close();
        return lista;
    }


    /**
     * Busca pela ID do produto
     * @param id
     * @return 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public Produto buscar(int id) throws Exception{
        open();

        stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from produto inner join categoria "
                + " on idcategoria = idcategoria where idproduto = ?");
        stmt.setInt(1, id);
        Produto prod = null;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            prod = new Produto(rs.getInt("idproduto"), rs.getString("nome"), 
                    rs.getInt("estoque"), rs.getDouble("preco"), rs.getDate("validade"));
            Categoria cat = new Categoria(rs.getInt("idcategoria"), 
                    rs.getString("nomecategoria"));
            prod.setCategoria(cat);
        }
        close();
        return prod;
    }

    public void excluir(int id)throws Exception{
        open();
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("delete from produto where idproduto = ?");
        stmt.setInt(1, id);
        stmt.execute();
        close();
    }


    public void editar(Produto prod)throws Exception{
        open();
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("update produto set nome = ?, estoque = ?, preco = ?, "
                + " validade = ?, categoria_idcategoria = ? where idproduto = ?");
        stmt.setString(1, prod.getNome());
        stmt.setInt(2, prod.getEstoque());
        stmt.setDouble(3, prod.getPreco());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        stmt.setString(4, sdf.format(prod.getValidade()));
        stmt.setInt(5, prod.getCategoria().getIdCategoria());
        stmt.setInt(6, prod.getIdProduto());

        stmt.execute();
        close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just find out.

The c:forEach items= must be for the parameter "${lista}" and not just "lista".

Solved. Thanks anyway.